# Matching entries from several input files

Tags: awk

My `FileA` content is:

```
 LetterA     LetterM  12
 LetterB     LetterC  45
 LetterB     LetterG  23
```

`FileB` content is:

```
 LetterA    23   43    LetterZ
 LetterB    21   71    LetterC
```

I want to write original `FileA` entry plus entry `$2-$3` from `FileB` if
`FileA $1 = FileB $1 && FileA $2 = FileB $4`.
For the ouput like this:

```
 LetterB     LetterC  45   -50
```

I can do it using bash loop

```
 while read ENTRY
 do
    COLUMN1=$(cut -f 1 $ENTRY)
    COLUMN2=$(cut -f 2 $ENTRY)
    awk -v COLUMN1="$COLUMN1" -v COLUMN2="COLUMN2" -v ENTRY="$ENTRY"   
         '($1==COLUMN1 && $4==COLUMN2) 
         {print ENTRY,$2-$3}' FileB
 done < FileA
```

However, this loop is too slow.  Is there a way to do this using awk without looping?
To take several input files -> match their content -> print wanted output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be solved in awk one-liner:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1":"$2]=$0; next}
     NR>FNR && $1":"$4 in a{print a[$1":"$4], $2-$3}' fileA fileB
```

OR even more concise (with thanks to @JS웃):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1$2]=$0;next}$1$4 in a{print a[$1$4],$2-$3}' file{A,B}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm! Just wanted to ask: why `$1":"$4 in a` works, but when I tried only `$1 in a` it didn't work?

Comment: I don't know if that's a one-liner, but it's a nice little demo of how awk is a lot more powerful than commonly understood.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: When I was building this awk solution it was 1 liner but while posting I broke into 2 lines for better readability :P

Comment: @JohnZwinck Your one-liner `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1$2]=$0;next}$1$4 in a{print a[$1$4],$2-$3}' File{A,B}` :)

Comment: @JS웃: As always your 1 liner is even smaller :P

Comment: @JS웃: I have added your solution to my answer as an alternative. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to try it with Python and Numpy for a slightly unorthodox but hopefully fast solution:

```
import numpy as np

# load the files into arrays with automatically determined types per column
a = np.genfromtxt("fileA", dtype=None)
b = np.genfromtxt("fileB", dtype=None)

# concatenate the string columns (n.b. assumes no "foo" "bar" and "fo" "obar")
aText = np.core.defchararray.add(a['f0'], a['f1'])
bText = np.core.defchararray.add(b['f0'], b['f3'])

# find the locations where the strings from A match in B, and print the values
for index in np.where(np.in1d(aText, bText)):
    aRow = a[index][0]
    bRow = b[bText == aText[index]][0]
    print '{1} {2} {3} {0}'.format(bRow[1] - bRow[2], *aRow)
```

Edit: it's fast once it gets going, but the time spent loading the files is unfortunately longer than @anubhava's excellent solution using awk.